# PHP pass associative array from one function to another wihle keeping keys intact

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have two functions and one array

function componentBuildRoute(&$query)
{
   $page = "";
    $segments = array();

```
//PAGE
if(isset($query["page"])){
    $page = $query["page"];
    unset($query["page"]);
} else {
    $page = "front";
}

//USERID
if(isset($query["userid"])){
    $segments["userid"] = $query["userid"];
    unset($query["userid"]);
}

//OPTION
if(isset($query["option"])){
    $segments["option"] = $query["option"];
    unset($query["option"]);
}

//CATID
if(isset($query["catid"])){
    $segments["catid"] = $query["catid"];
    $category_alias = getCategoryTitle($query["catid"]);
    $segments["category_alias"] = $category_alias;  
    unset($query["catid"]);
}
```

switch ($page) {

```
    //page?"show_search",$catid,$option
    case "show_search":
        $segments["page"] = "mostrar_busqueda";
    break;

    //case "show_category",$catid,$option,$expand,$text_search,$order,$limitstart,$plugins  
    case "show_category":
        $segments["page"] = "mostrar_categoria";
    break;

    //case "show_rules",$option)
    case "show_rules":
        $segments["page"] = "mostrar_reglas";
    break;

    //case "show_ad",$adid,$option,$plugins
    case "show_ad":
        $segments["page"] = "mostrar_clasificado";
    break;

}
```

return $segments;

}

/**
* Method to parse Route
* @param array $segments
*/ 
function componentParseRoute($segments)
{
    $vars = array();

```
// Get the active menu item.
$menu   = &JSite::getMenu();
$item   = &$menu->getActive();
$vars["Itemid"] = $item -> id;

//OPTION
if(isset($segments["option"])){
    $vars["option"] = $segments["option"];
}


//CATID
if(isset($segments["catid"])){
    $vars["catid"] = $segments["catid"];
}


//$adid
if(isset($segments["adid"])){
    $vars["adid"] = $segments["adid"];
}

switch($segments["page"]){
    //?page="show_profile",$userid,$option
    case "mostrar_perfil":
        $vars["page"] = "show_profile";
    break;

    //page?"show_search",$catid,$option
    case "mostrar_busqueda":
        $vars["page"] = "show_search";
    break;

    //case show_category
            //may use $catid,$option,$expand,$text_search,$order,$limitstart,$plugins
    case "mostrar_categoria":
        $vars["page"] = "show_category";
    break;

    //case "show_rules",$option
    case "mostrar_reglas":
        $vars["page"] = "show_rules";
    break;

    //case "show_ad",$adid,$option,$plugins
    case "mostrar_clasificado":
        $vars["page"] = "show_ad";
    break;
}
echo "VARS 2: <pre>";
print_r($vars);
echo "</pre>";

return $vars;
```

}

but I am not passing $segments['word']...word3'] to the second function.

I am passing

```
$segments[0];
$segments[1];
etc...
```

How can I pass the whole array to second function, keys and their values

```
$segments['word'] = value...
$segments['word1']
$segments['word2']
```

since the query may not always contain the word1, or word2, I think that I need to specify by key which value I am referring to.

Thank you,

Comment: I don't understand.  Would you clarify your question, format your code, and clarify what those functions are doing and how you're using them?

Comment: You're not passing *anything* to `B()`...

Comment: I have posted the real code, I am sorry for messy short posting before

Answer (score 1):

Use the array_keys function.  It will return an array of keys from the given associative array.

Comment: profitphp I have edited the question b/c I did not explain myself clearly. Could you take a look

Answer (score 1):

I have hard time understanding what you want but as far as i do
gues this will be the solution

```
 function A (){
  $segments = array();
  $segments['word']=$var1;
  $segments['word2']=$var2;
  $segments['word3']=$var3;

  return $segments;
}

function B ($segments){
  $someVar=$segments['word'];
  $someVar1=$segments['word'];
  $someVar2=$segments['word'];
  $vars['other_stuff']...

  return $vars;
}

   $arr = a();
   $barr = b($arr);
```

Comment: Breeze, I have edited my question b/c I did a poor explanation of what I want to accomplish. Could you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish as your question is a bit unclear and the code you presented is not correct, but I'll try to give some examples of what you may be looking for, given the following function A:

```
function A(){
  $segments = array();
  $segments['word'] = 'var1';
  $segments['word2'] = 'var2';
  $segments['word3'] = 'var3';

  return $segments;
}
```

**Option 1) Call function *A* from function *B*:**

```
function B(){
  $segments = A();
  // Do whatever you need with the $segments here
}
```

**Option 2) Pass returned array from function *A* to function *B*:**

```
function B($segments){
  // Do whatever you need with the $segments here
}

$segments = A();

B($segments);
```

**Option 3) Pass individual values returned from function *A* to function *B*:**

```
function B($var1, $var2){
  // Do whatever you need with the $var1 and $var2
}

$segments = A();

B($segments['word'], $segments['word2']);
```

If you can clarify your question and tell us exactly what you're trying to accomplish then we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Sarah, I have edit the question. I was not posting the question right.

Comment: It still makes no sense. Can you show an example of how you're calling function B and what you're passing to it? Also, you're referencing $var, $var1, $var2, and $vars in the functions, yet you're not setting them anywhere to begin with (which would produce an undefined variable notice. Can you clean up your code to provide real-world examples that we can work with?